# ocaml input_char

Tags: file, input, ocaml

I am trying to read a char from a file being passed in via the stdinput in ocaml. I was wondering why I keep getting a unit when I can print_char the char that I receive in the following code. Also, I am trying to make a list of these characters which will not work as of now.

```
let () =
let charList = [] in 
let inchar = open_in Sys.argv.(1) in
    try 
            while true do
                let c = Char.uppercase(input_char inchar) in
                    print_char c; print_int (List.length charList);c::charList
            done
    with End_of_file -> close_in inchar;(*; print_int (List.length charList); printTest charList;*)
```

;;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code does not modify `charList`, so `charList` remains an empty list throughout the whole execution.

Moreover, if you define
`let charList = []` then `charList` is immutable.

You might try something along these lines:

```
let () =
    let charList = ref [] in
    let inchar = open_in Sys.argv.(1) in
  try
    while true do
      let c = Char.uppercase (input_char inchar) in
            charList := c :: !charList
    done
  with End_of_file ->
        charList := List.rev !charList;
        close_in inchar;
        print_int (List.length !charList);
        List.iter print_char !charList
```

Some more comments:

- reading input char by char is very  inefficient, use for instance `input_line`.
- your post mentions `Sys.argv.(1)` and the standard input, but those are two distinct things
- if you want to read a whole file and store it in memory, search for "ocaml input file", there are many examples on the net, like https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/fa.caml/EEinP7-yAko/dPSaR0eOkw4J or http://camltastic.blogspot.fr/2008/09/tip-read-all-lines-from-file-most.html

Comment: That is actually what I ended up doing but somehow came up with it before this post. Happy for the help and the confirmation to know I ended up taking the right path.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something more functional :

```
let rec read inchar char_list =
  try
    read inchar ((Char.uppercase (input_char inchar))::char_list)
  with End_of_file -> char_list

let () =
  let inchar = open_in Sys.argv.(1) in
  let char_list = read inchar [] in
  close_in inchar
```

Comment: a fitting answer for stack overflow :-) this won't be tail-call optimised due to the try-with (the recursive call to "read" is not the final thing happening, the with-part may happen afterwards). You can avoid this by making an inchar-wrapper like `let inchar_opt c = try Some input_char c with End_of_file -> None` and matching on Some|None in read.

Comment: and (at least in newest ocaml?) you can do File.with_file_in now, which takes care of closing the channel for you